# How to import moment.js in ES6 using npm?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am using angular js and nodejs along with ES6. I want to import the moment.js in the angular js code. I did `'npm install moment --save'`

Now I am able to see moment.js file in moment folder which is inside node modules.

and in my app.js file I have wriiten like this

```
'import moment from 'moment';
```

But if search something with date range It is showing error in console. Can anybody help me how to do this..?

Comment: Is `app.js` node.js file ? If yes, then use `var moment = require('moment');`

Comment: No Mukesh. I am talking about app.js in angular

Comment: Are you going to tell us what the error is?

Answer (score 27):

Currently, to use ES6 module syntax, you need to use a transpiler e.g. Babel, since node.js and most browsers do not yet support ES6 module syntax.

Babel and webpack are great for this. [Here](http://www.2ality.com/2015/04/webpack-es6.html) is a nice example:

Once you have it configured properly, you invoke moment as such:

```
import moment from 'moment';
console.log(moment.now());
```

Answer (score 14):

**Since version 2.10.0** moment is written in ES6 :

```
import moment from './node_modules/moment/src/moment';
// Note the 'src/' to import the ES6 version and not the CJS build
```

However for now it seems there is no way to import only a subset of functions, you have to import the whole thing.

Answer (score 9):

The option, that worked for  me is:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Answer (score 3):

the code you written wont work.its not

```
//wont work
'import moment from moment'; this is wrong.
//this will work
import moment from 'moment';
or
import 'moment';
```

if these wont work.then try it using web-pack to expose moment to globally.

Comment: It is a typo. Not relevant to actual question.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you are looking.

```
import moment from 'moment'
import it from 'moment/locale/it'
import { utc } from 'moment'
moment.locale('it')
```

You can read the related issue here.
https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2608

Answer (score 3):

```
const moment = require('moment')
```

This worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use this librairie instead : 
https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

load the js files :

```
<script src="components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>
```

inject moment dependency in your app controller :

```
  var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['angularMoment']);
```

Comment: Hi Anlainlb. I am using es6 along with webpack. If I use node modules , webpack can build the front end code. So I want to do in that way

Answer (score 0):

Here, this works:

```
import moment from 'moment';
window.moment = moment;
```